# how to distinct or group by on my rows to get my result?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my database (SQL Server):

Table1:

```
ID        Name
1          a
2          a
3          b
```

I want this result

```
Name    count
a       2
b       1
```

how can i handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the aggregate function **`COUNT`** with **`GROUP BY`** clause.

**Query**

```
select [Name], count([ID]) as [Count]
from [your_table_name]
group by [Name]
order by [Name];
```

Or if you want to sort the result in descending order of `count`, then

```
select [Name], count([ID]) as [Count]
from [your_table_name]
group by [Name]
order by count([ID]) desc; -- for ascending order remove desc
```